# Find Specific Open File Dialog and populate

Tags: vb.net, window, find, findwindow, identify

I'm trying to find a method to identify a Open File Dialog and send a message to the "file name" field. Afterwards it needs to send an "Enter" key or "Open" command to the button.

I'm doing this in VB, but I'm sure I can cope if someone can help in C# as well.

I've been digging through the API this entire day and came up with a couple of possibilities but I am unfamiliar with how to implement this in DotNet4.
I used to work with API in VB6 but it seems like things are a bit different now.

If someone could provide me with a small example I'd be grateful.

Some of the API I've looked at is FindWindow and FindWindowEx.

Edit:

I found some code that is worth looking at. This code needs to be used inside a module.
I will post more as I find more answers.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

Module modEnumWindows

Private windowList As New ArrayList
Private errMessage As String

Public Delegate Function MyDelegateCallBack(ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Boolean
Declare Function EnumWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal x As MyDelegateCallBack, ByVal y As Integer) As Integer

Declare Auto Function GetClassName Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
    ByVal lpClassName As System.Text.StringBuilder, _
    ByVal nMaxCount As Integer) As Integer

Declare Auto Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" _
   (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
   ByVal lpClassName As System.Text.StringBuilder, _
   ByVal nMaxCount As Integer) As Integer


Private Function EnumWindowProc(ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Boolean

    'working vars
    Dim sTitle As New StringBuilder(255)
    Dim sClass As New StringBuilder(255)

    Try

        Call GetClassName(hwnd, sClass, 255)
        Call GetWindowText(hwnd, sTitle, 255)

        windowList.Add(sClass.ToString & ", " & hwnd & ", " & sTitle.ToString)

    Catch ex As Exception
        errMessage = ex.Message
        EnumWindowProc = False
        Exit Function
    End Try

    EnumWindowProc = True

End Function



Public Function getWindowList(ByRef wList As ArrayList, Optional ByVal errorMessage As String = "") As Boolean

    windowList.Clear()

    Try
        Dim del As MyDelegateCallBack
        del = New MyDelegateCallBack(AddressOf EnumWindowProc)
        EnumWindows(del, 0)
        getWindowList = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        getWindowList = False
        errorMessage = errMessage
        Exit Function
    End Try

    'wList.Clear()
    wList = windowList

End Function


End Module
```

By using this you'll be able to identify the Window Text, HWND and Class. Hope this helps people a bit. The next step for me will be to identify the field I wish to send the data to.

Comment: There's relevant code in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819570/how-can-i-control-the-size-of-the-help-window-using-system-windows-forms-help-sh/4820403#4820403  The class name of the dialog is "#32770"